# Is there any build tool available for linux that takes a web project & compresses text files, remove comments?

Tags: build, build-process

I am looking for a build tool that can take a dev version of a typical PHP project and can compress files such as HTML files, view files(PHP embedded in html or vice versa), JS & cSS files before they are deployed. I can do this for individual file using some online tools but that is time consuming. I want to automate this process. TIA!

Comment: Just to help you what to google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Wiki says -> `Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name. Please search for Minification (programming in Wikipedia to check for alternative titles or spellings.` And I want a single tool that does everything for me.

Comment: Sorry, SO ate my ending parenthesis. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) should work.

Answer (score 0):

For Java script and css you can use libraries like
Closure @ http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/ or
YUI Compressor @ http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

These tools can be run through ant tasks and would help to clean up and make the files concise.

Comment: I am looking for just one tool that takes care of JS, CSS, HTML and PHP files.